# Want to interact with windows applications using python

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, automation

I want to open the start menu and open some applications like paint,Ms word etc. Is there any module in python which can do these tasks ?

Answer (score 1):

[PyAutoGui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) is the right python module for something like this!

Using this module,  you can not only get the program to open the desired application, but also get it to perform certain tasks like button clicks, or entering text into input fields, etc. Basically it is a python library that allows you to programmatically control your keyboard and mouse actions.

[PyWinAuto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) is another such library made specifically for automating actions on the windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly with the python subprocess module.

`import subprocess`

`subprocess.Popen(['C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe'])`

But if you want to open start menu and click on the applications then **Pyautogui** module can be used.